# ios7 UITableView Cell Header UIButton Not Functioning

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uibutton

I am currently implementing code for a header to my UITableViewController. I have added a button to the "SectionHeader" cell in the storyboard which I have linked to another view. When I run the app on the simulator, the header shows up, but nothing happens when I press my button. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

```
-(UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
     static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"SectionHeader";
     HeaderTableViewCell *headerView = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
     if (headerView == nil){
         [NSException raise:@"headerView == nil.." format:@"No cells with matching CellIdentifier loaded from your storyboard"];
     }


    [(UIButton*) headerView.backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(back:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    return headerView;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
     return 50.0f;
}
```

Comment: This might not be the issue, but try returning `headerView.contentView`. From iOS8 I have found there to be issues with using cells to create header views as they can act strangely. In particular if you swipe delete a cell, you will find the header moves left unless you return the contentView. Also check backButton is not nil and can you post your `back` method?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It still doesn't work. Here is my code for back:

- (IBAction)back:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"checked");
}

Comment: Does the button show you pressing it down (as in it highlights)? If so, then your target method must be the issue. If not, then the input must be getting captured by something else: Either the button is behind another view on the header, or its disabled (check its enabled) or you have something else which is capturing the user touches.

Comment: It doesn't highlight. User interaction is enabled, also. I'm pretty sure something else is capturing the user touches.

Comment: I figured it out. It was something else in the code. Thanks for your help, Rory!

Comment: Is your `back:(id)` method is placed in your ViewController or HeaderTableViewCell class?